# Shopify app showing request blocked by an extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shopify, shopify-app

I have deployed my nodejs app on aws ec2 and its working fine while I am using it on the browser normally. But when I am accessing it from inside my Shopify app then it is showing that the request has been blocked by an extension.
I tried to access it in incognito mode also but got the same result.

Can someone please help.

Comment: Shopify blocks all http requests. You may want to check if you are loading any URL in http.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas Yes the initial url provided by aws is an http url.
its like ```http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-x.compute.amazonaws.com```
Should I buy a new domain and point towards it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify blocks all http requests. You may want to check if you are loading any URL in http

Update -

AWS provides secure URLs. Find it and use it instead!